# Adding color picker to a plugin to change the text color of content

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created a simple WordPress plugin that adds some content, So for example the admin would add the following text wrapped inside html elements I defined:

```
<div class="myplugin-content">
    The admin added this text.
</div>
```

Then in the plugin CSS files I have:

```
.myplugin-content{
    color: #000;
}
```

I want the admin to be able to edit that text color using a field in the admin dashboard admin menu.

I already created an admin menu:

```
function myplugin_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('my_plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin', 'my_plugin_page', '');
}

// Actions
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin_admin_menu');
```

How to add a color picker there, So when the user chooses a color and save the font color would be changed?

I noticed that feature in many plugins and themes settings and I searched about it, But couldn't find out the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything you need in this tutorial https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/